# Is it possible to resize the borders in libre office calc?

Tags: libreoffice

My question here is very basic-how do you resize the borders in libreoffice calc?

Comment: The size of the cells, or the DPI width of the borders between them (assuming you're placing borders)

Comment: **Which** border? Cell borders or Page margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the cell, 'format cells', and click the borders tab.  All the options are there.

Comment: @tohuwawohu, cell borders. Thank you for your help.